# ansible lineinfile module - combine quotes and double quotes

Tags: ansible

I am trying to add line that contains both single quotes and double quotes and I am failing to do so for an exhausted hour...

```
vars:
  line1: "a=\\\"a'b'c\\\""
  line2: 'a="a\''b\''c"'
tasks:
- name: lineinfile test
  lineinfile: dest=/tmp/tmp line={{item}}
  with_items:
    - "{{line1}}"
    - "{{line2}}"
```

the desired line is `a="a'b'c"`

the content of /tmp/tmp is

```
a="abc"
a=a'b'c
```

so neither do the trick.. ideas?

Comment: `line2: a=\\\"a\\\'b\\\'c\\\"` (don't ask me why :)

Comment: @dusan.bajic perfect!!! post as an answer please for future reference.

Comment: Using lineinfile is an antipattern- there are very few cases where `template` can't be used.

Comment: @tedder42 Well, I am using it to add lines to existsing configurtion files like bashrc, bash_aliases, fstab. As far as I know this is the only way. light up my eyes if I am missing something. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
line2: a=\\\"a\\\'b\\\'c\\\"
```

Anyone who can improve the answer with explanation is more than welcome to do so.